# Installing a kernel-mode driver manually in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, drivers

I have a `.sys` driver without the related `.inf` setup information. Is there any way that I can install it manually?

This is from a broken MSI - it checks for an ASUS laptop and gets the check wrong - so if there's a better way to, say, bypass that, that would be equally nice.

Comment: Exact laptop model?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: ASUS X53U.